# updating the content of a file stored on Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use javascript in order to set the contents of a file stored on Google Drive (for example, a .txt or .java file) to a specific String.

I know that the proper way to update a file stored on Google Drive is

```
function updateFile(fileId, fileMetadata, fileData, callback) {
    const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
    const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
    //console.log("fileId: "+fileId+" fileData: "+fileData);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("reader initialized");
        var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
        // Updating the metadata is optional and you can instead use the value from drive.files.get.
        var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
        var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(fileMetadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        base64Data +
        close_delim;

        var request = gapi.client.request({
                                          'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/' + fileId,
                                          'method': 'PUT',
                                          'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart', 'alt': 'json'},
                                          'headers': {
                                          'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
                                          },
                                          'body': multipartRequestBody});
        if (!callback) {
            callback = function(file) {
                console.log(file)
            };
        }
        request.execute(callback);
    }
}
```

but this has not worked in setting the content to a specific String.

Comment: paste the http request and response

Comment: I think your close_delim is missing a \r\n I do something like this at the very end.     string footer = "\r\n--" + boundry + "--\r\n";

Comment: I copied this directly off of the [Google Drive SDK website](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update). The request is `PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/{fileId}`

Comment: could I just read the String in base 64 and use that as the variable "base64data"? For example `function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str )));
}`

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. I found the answer to my problem. Using the method `updateFile` from my question:

```
function save(fileId, content){
    var contentArray = new Array(content.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
        contentArray[i] = content.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(contentArray);
    var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'text/plain'});
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({'fileId': fileId});
    request.execute(function(resp) {
        updateFile(fileId,resp,blob,changesSaved);
        //                 the callback^^^^^^
    });
}
```